# A question on the stability of $\operatorname{Cat}$ in $\operatorname{Cat}_\infty$

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cat{Cat}$Suppose we have a span in $\Cat$
$$ \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @> G>> X
\\ @VVFV
\\ B
\end{CD}
$$
We can view this as a span in $\Cat_\infty$. What useful conditions can we impose to ensure the pushout is still a 1-category?

As a specific example, is either of the following conditions sufficient?

- <strike>$F$ is injective on objects and arrows</strike>
- $F$ is injective on objects and arrows, and every isomorphism of the form $F(X) \cong F(Y)$ is in the image of $F : A(X,Y) \to B(F(X), F(Y))$
- Both $F$ and $G$ satisfy the property above

**Remark:** This second proposition is the property [$F$ is a monomorphism in $Cat_\infty$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/345686/167598) together with the proposition that $F$ is an isocofibration in $Cat$ so that if the pushout in $Cat_\infty$ is a 1-category, it's given by taking the the pushout in $Cat$. For the question as asked we can drop the isocofibration condition.

Being injective on objects is not sufficient, since we have a pushout square
in $\Cat_\infty$
$$ \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^1 @>>> 1
\\ @VVV @VVV
\\ 1 @>>> S^2
\end{CD} $$
and $S^1 \to 1$ can be given by a functor between 1-object categories.

As @AchimKrause points out in the comments, injective on objects and arrows is not sufficient either.

---

An example of a sufficient condition that does work (but is too restrictive for me) is if $A$, $B$, $X$ are all free categories and $F$ is obtained from an inclusion of the generating graphs.

In this case, we can compute this in the Bergner model structure on simplicially enriched categories. The map $A \to B$, when viewed in simplicial categories, is a cofibration between cofibrant objects (it is $\mathfrak{C}[-]$ applied to the inclusion of the generating graphs viewed as simplicial sets), and $X$ is cofibrant as well, and thus the pushout (which is obviously a 1-category) is a homotopy pushout, and thus computes the pushout in $\Cat_\infty$.

Another case that works, as described in the comments, is when $A$ and $B$ are groupoids and $F$ is a monomorphism in $Cat_\infty$; in this case, $B \cong A \amalg A'$, and thus the pushout in $Cat_\infty$ is $X \amalg A'$.

Comment: If F is an equivalence then I imagine the pushout is still a 1-category, but this is too restrictive.

Comment: Note that being injective on objects or on morphisms is not a condition stable under equivalence, and so it is unlikely to be of help. Maybe asking for one leg to be a replete inclusion will work, but I'm honestly skeptical there's a sensible condition for this.

Comment: For groupoids, something akin to your first condition should indeed work, namely that the functors are injective on $\pi_0$ and faithful. This should reduce to the corresponding statement for classifying spaces of groups.
For general categories, condition 1 is definitely not enough. You can consider a pushout where the upper right corner is an arbitrary category, the upper left corner is a disjoint union of multiple $\Delta^1$, and the l.l. corner is the localisation of the u.l. corner. Then the pushout is a localisation of the category you started with, and not generally a $1$-category.

Comment: @DenisNardin I was thinking about computing the pushout in the canonical model structure on Cat which is why I was focusing on the "injective on objects" condition. IIRC, the second of the two conditions I list the proposition "$F$ is a monomorphism in $Cat_\infty$" restricted to the case $F$ is injective on objects. So the equivalence-respecting condition would be to consider $F$ being a monomorphism in $Cat_\infty$.

Comment: @PushoutOfCategories "F is a monomorphism in $Cat_∞$" is precisely the condition of being (equivalent to) the inclusion of a replete subcategory. Unfortunately Achim's example shows that this is of course not nearly enough (every localization can be realized as a pushout along a replete subcategory!).

Comment: @DenisNardin Actually, the example of AchimKrause isn't of that form. While every $\infty$-category is the localization of a poset, the map from a disjoint union of $\Delta^1$ into that poset is not a monomorphism. E.g. the map $\{0 \leq 1 \} \amalg \{1' \leq 2\} \to \{0 \leq 1 \leq 2\}$ is not a monomorphism in $Cat_\infty$ because the domain doesn't have a map $1 \to 1'$ whose image is the identity on $1$. Similarly, the map from $\Delta^1$ to its localization is not a monomorphism either (since it lacks a map $1 \to 0$).

Comment: ... but maybe I misunderstand. The two descriptions of of "every $\infty$-category is a localization of a category" I know are **(1)** pushing out along a disjoint union of copies of the map from $\Delta^1$ to the interval groupoid (which fails the monomorphism condition), and **(2)** pushout along the map from a subcategory to its $\infty$-groupoidification  (which fails the 1-category condition). If there is another description that fits the condition of the post, it's not coming to mind.

Comment: Oic, I had miswritten the monomorphism condition; the preimages of isomorphisms have to exist in each relevant homset, not just once globally.

Comment: I found the hypothesis that $F$ be a monomorphism plausible, since it feels like whatever construction freely generates an $\infty$-category should be doing so by simply adding new points to the hom-sets, and shouldn't require any cells identifying morphisms. But I don't understand cofibrations well enough in simplicial categories to work it out there, I don't have enough proficiency with inner anodyne extensions to work it out in quasi-categories, and I haven't yet been able to work out the localization from simplicial objects to category objects in $Gpd_\infty$ to show it there.

Comment: A sufficient condition, that I've learnt from Viktoriya Ozornova and Martina Rovelli, is that the functor $F$ is a [Dwyer map](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dwyer+map). The proof is not trivial.

Comment: @PushoutOfCategories You are right, I was mistaken in saying that Achim's example is of this kind (the leg is a subcategory but not a *replete* subcategory).

Comment: @AndreaGagna Ah! I think that covers some of the cases I'm interested in, and I know a reference for the key fact underlying that argument. I've posted this example as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Martina Rovelli and I have indeed thought about the case of Dwyer morphisms before. Originally, we were also trying to employ Barwick-Kan, but I think there is the following subtle point there.

You have to specify how to look at a category as a particular relative category, and the natural way is to assign to a category $\mathcal{A}$ the pair $(\mathcal{A}, \mathrm{iso}(\mathcal{A}))$. However, I think this functor does not take Dwyer morphisms in categories to Dwyer morphisms in relative categories. Indeed, I think that already the inclusion of the object $a$ into the category ${a<b}$ is not a Dwyer morphism of relative categories. It seems that checking [Barwick-Kan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.1691.pdf) §§3.2-3.5 shows that you would need your homotopy to be a relative functor
$$
(a<b, \mathrm{id}) \times (0<1, \mathrm{max}) \to  (a<b, \mathrm{id})
$$
which maps $b0$ to $a$ and $b1$ to $b$, so that the weak equivalence $b0\to b1$ would map to a map which is not a weak equivalence.

**Edit May 2022:**
<del>Instead, we believe to have found an explicit proof using anodyne extensions now</del>
The question turned out to be far more subtle. As we were trying to use it in a joint work with Philip Hackney and Emily Riehl (https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.03660), the referee was pointing out that our proof did not work in a full generality. We have been thinking about these pushouts for a while since then, and we still believe that the statement holds true, although the proof is much more involved now (https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.02353).